# SQLite: Select all Names of given Colors

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite Database, two of the tables look like this:

```
ID    Name
1     Test1
2     Test2
3     Test3
4     Test4

ID    Color
1     Blue
1     White
1     Red
2     Green
2     Red
4     Black
```

In the first Tables, ID is unique, the second table lists colors an ID has, it can be from 0 to n colors.

Now I want to select all Names exactly once, that have one or more given color. Lets say, I want to have all names associated with blue, white and/or green. The resultset should have the IDs 1 and 2.

I am completly lost here, as I normally dont do any SQL. I am just familiar with very basic SQL. What I would do is Join the tables together, but I dont know how I do that, as ID is not unique in the second table. Also there would be the problem of IDs beeing duplicated in the resultset, if it has multiple colors that I want to select.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to have some primary/foreign key relationship between these tables to be able to apply a join.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this: ID in the first table is the primary key, ID in the second is indeed a foreign key!

Comment: You don't need to have ID unique in the 2nd table. A join would return multiple results as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a join for this. Get the list of IDs from the color table in a subquery, and fetch the names from the test table with an `in` clause:

```
sqlite> select * from tests where id in
        (select id from colors where name in ('Blue', 'White', 'Green'));
1|Test1
2|Test2
```

Duplicates don't matter in the subquery, but you could use `distinct` if you want that list without duplicates in other contexts.

Comment: I have now talkes to an SQL Expert (luckily I met him today). He gave me this statement: `SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.name FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE LOWER(t2.color) IN ("blue", "white", "green");` Can you tell me, which one is the better one? Both give me the same results.

Comment: There's only one way to know that: test both, find out which one is faster/more efficient on your dataset.